# C++ wrapper for openssl

Tags: c++, c, openssl

openssl provides very low-level C interface (raw char pointers, malloc/free, raw structs instead of classes) in its encryption/decryption library functions.

Is there specific security reason openssl is implemented and maintained as raw C despite of being claimed as C++ library?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Also, don't ask two questions in one go, this undermines the purpose of SO for being a searchable Q&A site.

Comment: @JensGustedt I have removed off-topic part of the question, pelase see edit

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: I did attempt to cover the major parts of X509 certificates in [sslpkix](https://github.com/jweyrich/sslpkix). If that's all you want, it might be of help. Beware there's no documentation available, but you can check the public test-case.

Comment: I'm here looking for a C++ wrapper as well.  I found your question with Google.  Too bad this community here is so obsessed with closing people's questions.  It didn't used to be this way.  SO used to be a good resource.

Comment: Eh, in 2019 you still has to re-invent a wheel when wrapping openssl for C++ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL does not claim to be a C++ library.  And it is implemented in C rather than C++ so that it is accessible to more platforms and programming languages.  Most cross-platform libraries are written in C for that same reason, though some do provide a C++ wrapper for convenience.  OpenSSL has no such wrapper of its own, so you will have to look for a third-party wrapper.  It is not a matter of security but of usability.  Most platforms/languages have provisions for using/accessing C libraries.  The same is not true for C++ libraries.